# commiting only the property change of a folder not the modified files inside it using svn commit

Tags: svn, properties, commit

hi i want to commit only the property of a folder not the locally modified files inside it.

when i am using svn commit it is commiting also the modified files.please tell me how to get

this .

thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you set a property with **svn propset** (adding to ignore list folder /help):

```
svn propset svn:ignore help
```

You can use --depth flag when running svn commit:

```
svn ci --depth=immediates
```

This will skip modifications made in files.You can also play with other values for **--depth**.

**UPDATE**

According to [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.depth) **--depth=immediates** limit the scope of operation to *the target and any immediate children thereof* . So, it's better to use

```
svn ci --depth=empty modified_target_folder
```

which limits the scope of operation to specified target only.

Comment: Actually `--depth=immediates` seems to checkin anything in the current directory, what you want is `--depth=empty`!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Isn't depend on where are you standing. Suppose you are in REPO folder and want to commit properties for REPO/FOLDER. Will it commit REPO/FOLDER contents as well?

Comment: I tried it one level up and immediates still wanted to commit the folder contents.

Comment: @WayneUroda do you commit with PATH: "cd REPO; svn ci --depth=immediates FOLDER " or "cd REPO; svn ci --depth=immediates . " ? - note the dot in the last case

Comment: `svn --depth=immediates FOLDER` still wants to commit every change directly in FOLDER (i.e. it will commit FOLDER/readme.txt). I see now what you are getting at, if you are in the folder ABOVE the folder where you changed the properties, yes you can use --depth=immediate. Trouble is, my folder is the top of the repo! Going above that gives me "svn: E155007: path is not a working copy".

Comment: @WayneUroda Thank you, I got your point and updated the answer